# Difference of 2 random variables is uniformly distribuetd.

Tags: distribution

Given:

x is a random variable distributed on [0, 1/2]

y is a random variable distributed on [0, 1/2]

Define z = x - y

Question: If the distribution of z is UNIFORM on [-1/2, +1/2], what are the  distributions of x and y that generate this uniformly distributed z?

Answer (score 1):

Answer:
`y=1/2-x` (almost surely)

Proof:
Consider Var(z).

```
Var(z)=E{[z-E(z)]^2}
=E{[x-y-E(x-y)]^2}
=E{[[x-E(x)]-[y-E(y)]]^2}
=Var(x)+Var(y)-2*E{[x-E(x)]*[y-E(y)]}
```

We knew that `Var(z)=1/12`, and `Var(x)=Var(y)=1/48`.
We must have `E{[x-E(x)]*[y-E(y)]}=-1/48`
Note that `corr(x,y) = E{[x-E(x)]*[y-E(y)]}/sqrt[Var(x)*Var(y)] = -1`
x and y must be perfectly anti-correlated.
Thus `y=1/2-x` (almost surely).
One will be able to verify that y is uniformly distributed on [0, 1/2]
And that `z=x-y=2x-1/2` is uniform on [-1/2, 1/2].

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I guess that your solution is also consistent with having x uniformly distributed on [0, 1/2], where fx = 2 (so the total area = 1). 

Let, y = 1/2 - x, and hence, z = x - y = 2x - 1/2. 

Therefore Ex = 1/4, var(x) = 1/48, 

Therefore, Ez = E(2x - 1/2) = 0, and 

var(z) = var(2x - 1/2) = 4 var(x) - 0 = 1/12.